# Running GKE pods on a specific internal IP

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

We're running a private Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud. We have very little Kubernetes knowledge and so are struggling to know how to tackle this issue.

A specific internal IP address (10.*.0.0) has been whitelisted to allow the cluster on this IP address to access a sensitive internal service (access to a MySQL instance). This worked great but now we want to migrate from one cluster to multiple clusters but we need all these clusters to be able to route traffic through this one whitelisted IP address. The clusters and the whitelisted IP address share the same VPC network.

How should we approach this? We looked into creating a ClusterIP service but that doesn't allow specifying an internal IP address. Load balancers also aren't what we need as they look to handle external traffic while we're interested only in internal traffic.

Comment: have you looked into [Internal load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) direction?

Comment: Interesting, let me read that doc and investigate. Thanks for the pointer @Vitalii!

Comment: @Vitalii I'm not sure an internal load balancer is suited to my use case. I have one IP address in my VPC network whitelisted to access a MySQL instance but I want several clusters to be able to route traffic through this whitelisted IP address. The internal load balancer concept looks to be aimed at ingress, i.e. multiple external requests being directed to one IP address and then distributed to multiple different internal IP addresses. Any thoughts?

Comment: yes, you are right here. my solution wont help. you resolved or still in progress?

Comment: @Vit Still an open issue on our side so any further help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As NAT doesn't allow you to have in and out IP addresses in the same subnet, and GKE doesn't allow you to use separate subnet for another node pool, the only solution for this task would be a SQL or TCP proxy installed on a separate VM that has `specific internal IP address (10.*.0.0) on its network interface`.

Your application instances will connect to that VM on a specific port and the Proxy software initiate a new connection from it's own IP address to your MySQL instance. All responses will be forwarded back to originator of the request.

Please take a look at the following example of implementing TCP proxy using Nginx (Despite the example is related to MS SQL it should work for MySQL as well with just different port: 3306, and you probably don't need UDP related section):

- [Reverse Proxy MS SQL with Nginx](https://dev.to/jordonr/reverse-proxy-ms-sql-with-nginx-3e90)

```
stream {
    upstream dbtcp {
        server db1:1433;
    }

    upstream dbudp {
        server db1:1434;
    }

    server {
        listen 1433;
        proxy_pass dbtcp;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s; # detect failure quickly
    }

    server {
        listen 1434 udp;
        proxy_pass dbudp;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s; # detect failure quickly
    }
}
```

More complex but also more flexible and feature-rich way is using SQL aware proxy like [**ProxySQL**](https://proxysql.com/documentation/installing-proxysql/) It's an open source project made available under the GPL v3 license.

- [ProxySQL Github link](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql)